# C#/WPF: PropertyChanged for all Properties in ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I've a class like this:

```
public class PersonViewModel : ViewModelBase //Here is the INotifyPropertyChanged Stuff
{
    public PersonViewModel(Person person)
    {
        PersonEntity = person;
    }

    public Person PersonEntity { 
        get { return PersonEntity.Name; }
        private set { PersonEntity.Name = value; RaisePropertyChanged("PersonEntity");
    }

    public string Name { 
        get { return PersonEntity.Name; }
        set { PersonEntity.Name = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
    } 
    public int Age{ 
        get { return PersonEntity.Age; }
        set { PersonEntity.Age= value; RaisePropertyChanged("Age");
    } 

    public void ChangePerson(Person newPerson)
    {
        //Some Validation..
        PersonEntity = newPerson;
    }
```

My TextBoxes are bound to Name and Age of the ViewModel.
If I change the _person object in the ViewModel, do I have to call for each Property a RaisePropertyChanged again or is there a way to do this automaticly (in my concret example I have about 15 Properties..)?

Thanks for any help.

Cheers
Joseph

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You can indicate all properties have changed by using `null` or `string.Empty` for the property name in `PropertyChangedEventArgs`. This is mentioned in the documentation for [PropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?#remarks).

Comment: GREAT, I was looking for something like this since months.. I always had to call RaisePropertyChanged for each Property in my ViewModels :-)

Answer (score 1):

One other solution I used to tackle the problem of: first setting the value and then calling the `PropertyChangedEventArgs` is by adding a `Set` function in my `ViewModelBase` which looks like this:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected bool Set<T>(ref T backingField, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyname = null)
    {
        // Check if the value and backing field are actualy different
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingField, value))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Setting the backing field and the RaisePropertyChanged
        backingField = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(propertyname);
        return true;
   }
}
```

Instead of doing this:

```
public string Name { 
    get { return PersonEntity.Name; }
    set { PersonEntity.Name = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
}
```

You can now achieve the same by doing this:

```
public string Name { 
    get { return PersonEntity.Name; }
    set { Set(ref PersonEntity.Name,value);
}
```