# PropertyChanged for all Properties: Message=Property not found

Tags: mvvm-light

I want to raise `PropertyChanged` for all 20 Properties of my `ViewModel` in once and get the solution:

```
RaisePropertyChanged(String.Empty)
```

see: [C#/WPF: PropertyChanged for all Properties in ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859946/c-wpf-propertychanged-for-all-properties-in-viewmodel)

Since I use `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.ViewModelBase.RaisePropertyChanged` of MVVM Light, I get the runtime error:

```
   Message=Property not found
   ParamName=""
   Source=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WPF4
```

This is because MVVM Light check all Property-Names.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

You could [file a bug report](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic) and, in the meantime, [change MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source, you'll see that this exception is only raised when you're compiling as DEBUG. If you compile as RELEASE you won't get this behavior anymore.

Like Kent said, I changed the source to do a Debug.Writeline instead of throwing an exception. I don't like the default behavior, especially since I will commonly re-raise PropertyChanged to a parent ViewModel from a list of child ViewModels.