# Good way to refresh databinding on all properties of a ViewModel when Model changes

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

### Short Version

If I update the Model object that my ViewModel wraps, what's a *good* way to fire property-change notifications for all the model's properties that my ViewModel exposes?

### Detailed Version

I'm developing a WPF client following the MVVM pattern, and am attempting to handle incoming updates, from a service, to data being displayed in my Views. When the client receives an update, the update appears in the form of a DTO which I use as a Model.

If this model is an update to an existing model being shown in the View, I want the associated ViewModel to update its databound properties so that the View reflects the changes.

Let me illustrate with an example. **Consider my Model:**

```
class FooModel
{
  public int FooModelProperty { get; set; }
}
```

**Wrapped in a ViewModel:**

```
class FooViewModel
{
  private FooModel _model;

  public FooModel Model 
  { 
    get { return _model; }
    set 
    { 
      _model = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged("Model"); 
    }
  }

  public int FooViewModelProperty
  {
    get { return Model.FooModelProperty; }
    set 
    {
      Model.FooModelProperty = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("FooViewModelProperty");
    }    
}
```

**The Problem:**

When an updated model arrives, I set the ViewModel's Model property, like so:

```
instanceOfFooVM.Model = newModel;
```

This causes `OnPropertyChanged("Model")` to fire, but not `OnPropertyChanged("FooViewModelProperty")`, unless I call the latter explicitly from `Model`'s setter. So a View bound to `FooViewModelProperty` won't update to display that property's new value when I change the Model.

Explicitly calling `OnPropertyChanged` for every exposed Model property is obviously not a desirable solution, and neither is taking the `newModel` and iterating through its properties to update the ViewModel's properties one-by-one.

What's a better approach to this problem of updating a whole model and needing to fire change notifications for all its exposed properties?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx):

> The PropertyChanged event can indicate all properties on the object have changed by using either null or String.Empty as the property name in the PropertyChangedEventArgs.

Comment: I'm sure I read this at some point, but I'd utterly forgotten about it. This seems like the best approach when a ViewModel's entire Model has changed. Many thanks!

Comment: I use this method all the time to refresh objects. I would not suggest doing this after every property change but for an initial object load it works great.

Comment: if using MVVM-light this will give an error. there's no actual solution here unfortunately but see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554831

Comment: My tests showed that I only String.Empty works. Null didn't work for me

Comment: @Alon Catz right, I also tried using `null` as `propertyName` value and didn't get all class binded properties updated, However using `string.Empty` as `propertyName` value **does** update all class binded properties.

Comment: @AlonCatz I agree, `null` does not work. `""` or `string.Empty` does.

Answer (score 7):

One option is to listen to your own events, and make a helper routine to raise the other notifications as required.

This can be as simple as adding, in your constructor:

```cs
public FooViewModel()
{
    this.PropertyChanged += (o,e) =>
      {
          if (e.PropertyName == "Model")
          {
               OnPropertyChanged("FooViewModelProperty");
               // Add other properties "dependent" on Model here...
          }
      };
}
```

Comment: I expected to see something AOP-like among the answers, but I really love simplicity. Up-voted :). Maybe another approach could be just extract all dependent OnPropertyChanged invocations to a separate method and call it from FooModel's setter.

Comment: @Anvaka: I've got, internally, a helper routine that does this via "AddDepedentProperty" and expression trees... It's a useful option.

Comment: Thanks for this approach. Its downside, though, is that it preserves the problem of having to maintain a set of `OnPropertyChanged` calls for all the properties exposed by my ViewModel; when properties are added, for instance, this set must be kept up to date. I believe @Joe White has hit upon what I need...

Comment: @djacobson: That's a good option, too- be aware that it redoes EVERY property bound to that object - if your VM is a simple Model wrapper, it's perfect - but if it includes other application logic, it can trigger more notifications than required.

Comment: Good call, and something I will certainly keep in mind! In my case, I think it will be a trade-off worth making... at least until proven otherwise. :)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever your `Model` property is set, subscribe to its own `PropertyChanged` event. When your handler gets called, fire off your own `PropertyChanged` event. When the `Model` is set to something else, remove your handler from the old `Model`.

Example:

```cs
class FooViewModel
{
    private FooModel _model;

    public FooModel Model 
    { 
        get { return _model; }
        set 
        { 
            if (_model != null)
            {
                _model.PropertyChanged -= ModelPropertyChanged;
            }

            if (value != null)
            {
                value.PropertyChanged += ModelPropertyChanged;
            }

            _model = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("Model"); 
        }
    }

    public int FooViewModelProperty
    {
        get { return Model.FooModelProperty; }
        set 
        {
            Model.FooModelProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FooViewModelProperty");
        } 
    }

    private void ModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Here you will need to translate the property names from those
        // present on your Model to those present on your ViewModel.
        // For example:
        OnPropertyChanged(e.PropertyName.Replace("FooModel", "FooViewModel"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged 

    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(String.Empty))
```

For VB.net if anybody else needs it. If you have already implemented "INotifyPropertyChanged" then the last line is all you need.