# WPF binding issue while using NavigationCommands.BrowseBack property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, navigation, windows-phone-8

I wonder why this behavior happening in my page.
I have a page (say 'x') which has set of text boxes which are defined inside a container say a stack panel and the data is bounded with this stack panel using datacontext in c#.
now when I am navigating to another page and again moving back to that page (page 'x') (URI Navigation) the data binding will happen and the fields will be filled buy the object's data as the getter method of the object's property will get called ,but by pressing back button (NavigationCommands.BrowseBack) there will be no data binding happens in the page. no field will take the date as the getters method of properties of the object will not called  in this case!!
I don't want to do it in back end by reffering to each text box and assigning values to them.

any one having the same issue or solution for that please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to update your bindings manually. For example you could write the following code as an extension to "BenCr's" answer in this post [Is there a way to refresh all bindings in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157068/is-there-a-way-to-refresh-all-bindings-in-wpf)

```
var temp = yourStackPanel.DataContext;
yourStackPanel.DataContext = null;
yourStackPanel.DataContext = temp;
```

Comment: :basically I first assign it to null then the object. But it doesn't help