# Why does `PropertyChanged?.Invoke()` only work in the concerning object but not from the ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a `JobView` which contains a `ItemsControl`. It displays a `DataTemplate` for each "job" in `Jobs`. A job can be started/stopped by clicking the buttons in the `DataTemplate`. The DataTemplate also contains the `Status` of a job (started/stopped) but this is not updated when in trigger the `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(...)` event from the `JobViewModel`.

When i move the `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(...)` to the (abstract) `RJob` class (for a specific variable in that class), it works fine thought this does not feel nice to me. I don't want to add "view logic" to my classes to update a view. I want to keep this logic in the ViewModels.

I also want to avoid that i need to do a `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(...)` for each variable in a class (`RJob` in this example) that i show in a view. I prefer to do something like `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(job)` so i automatically updates all showed variables of the concerning job.

**I have 2 questions about this:**

- What is de convinient place to trigger the `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(...)`?
- Is it possible to trigger the `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(...)` on object level instead of on property level so it updates all binded properties without creating a `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(...)` for each individual property?

*Note that i cleaned up the code a bit for this question.*

---

My `JobView.xaml`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ECRO.MVVM.View.JobView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ECRO.MVVM.ViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" Height="780">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModel:JobViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <UserControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="jobTemplate">
                <Grid Height="90" Width="760">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="677*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="123*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border CornerRadius="10"
                    Background="#353340"
                    Height="80"
                    Margin="10,0,10,0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                        <Grid>
                            ...

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                                    Margin="5 2 0 0">
                            <Label Content="Naam" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabel}" Margin="0 -5 0 -5"/>
                            <Label Content="Status" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabel}" Margin="0 -5 0 -5"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="2">
                            <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabel}" Margin="0 -5 0 -5"/>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Status}"  Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabel}" Margin="0 -5 0 -5"/>
                        </StackPanel>


                            <Border Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                    Grid.Column="2"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                    Margin="0 0 20 0">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Button Content="Start" 
                                        Style="{StaticResource DarkButton}" 
                                        Command="{Binding DataContext.StartJobCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                                    <Button Content="Stop" 
                                        Style="{StaticResource DarkButton}" 
                                        Command="{Binding DataContext.StopJobCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                                   ...
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Jobs" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlock}"/>
        <ScrollViewer Width="780" Height="700">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Jobs}" 
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource jobTemplate}"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

---

*Not working `JobViewModel` with `RJob`:*

My `JobViewModel`

```
using ECRO.Class;
using ECRO.Core;
using ECRO.RJobs;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ECRO.MVVM.ViewModel
{
    class JobViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<RJob> _jobs;
        public ObservableCollection<RJob> Jobs { get => _jobs; set { _jobs = value; } }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        public RelayCommand StartJobCmd { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand StopJobCmd { get; set; }

        ...

        public JobViewModel()
        {
            _jobs = Engine.Instance.RJobs;

            StartJobCmd = new RelayCommand(o => { 
                RJob job = (RJob)o;
                job.Start();
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(job)));
            });
            StopJobCmd = new RelayCommand(o => {
                RJob job = (RJob)o;
                job.Stop();
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(job)));
            });
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

My abstract `RJob` which is inherrited by all jobs:

```
...

namespace ECRO.Class
{
    public abstract class RJob
    {
        private JobStatus jobStatus;
        public JobStatus Status { get => this.jobStatus; }

        ...

        public JobStatus Start()
        {
            if (active && jobStatus != JobStatus.Running)
            {
                try {
                    runTask();
                    jobStatus = JobStatus.Running;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    this.jobStatus = JobStatus.Failed;
                    Log.Error($"Some error occurred in job \"{Name}\", check the job log for more details.");
                    Log.Error(e, this);
                }
            }
            SaveConfiguration();
            return jobStatus;
        }

        public JobStatus Stop(bool saveConfig = true)
        {
            if (jobStatus == JobStatus.Running)
            {
                jobExcecuteTimer.Change(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
                jobStatus = JobStatus.Stopped;
            }
            if (saveConfig)
            {
                SaveConfiguration();
            }
            return jobStatus;
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

---

*Working `JobViewModel` & `RJob`:*

My `JobViewModel`

```
using ECRO.Class;
using ECRO.Core;
using ECRO.RJobs;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ECRO.MVVM.ViewModel
{
    class JobViewModel 
    {
        private ObservableCollection<RJob> _jobs;
        public ObservableCollection<RJob> Jobs { get => _jobs; set { _jobs = value; } }

        public RelayCommand StartJobCmd { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand StopJobCmd { get; set; }

        ...

        public JobViewModel()
        {
            _jobs = Engine.Instance.RJobs;

            StartJobCmd = new RelayCommand(o => { 
                ((RJob)o).Start();
            });
            StopJobCmd = new RelayCommand(o => {
                ((RJob)o).Stop();
            });
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

My abstract `RJob` which is inherrited by all jobs:

```
...

namespace ECRO.Class
{
    public abstract class RJob : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private JobStatus jobStatus;
        public JobStatus Status { get => this.jobStatus; }
        
        ...

        public JobStatus Start()
        {
            if (active && jobStatus != JobStatus.Running)
            {
                try {
                    runTask();
                    jobStatus = JobStatus.Running;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Status"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    this.jobStatus = JobStatus.Failed;
                    Log.Error($"Some error occurred in job \"{Name}\", check the job log for more details.");
                    Log.Error(e, this);
                }
            }
            SaveConfiguration();
            return jobStatus;
        }

        public JobStatus Stop(bool saveConfig = true)
        {
            if (jobStatus == JobStatus.Running)
            {
                jobExcecuteTimer.Change(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
                jobStatus = JobStatus.Stopped;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Status"));   
            }
            if (saveConfig)
            {
                SaveConfiguration();
            }
            return jobStatus;
        }
        
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: RJob must implement INotifyPropertyChanged and fire the PropertyChanged event for every property that is shown in the view. That is the standard implementation.

Comment: Ok, that would mean that i must add lots and lots of `PropertyChanged` events in the whole class. Is it possible to make a kind of general implementation in a class which fires the event if one of its properties is updated? It still feels dirty to fire these events in "logic/core" classes to update views.

Comment: You should typically not bind to your model, or "logic/core" classes at all. That is what the viewModel is for. So you might consider renaming JobViewModel to Job**s**ViewModel, and create a proper JobViewModel that owns a Job, and takes care of all the UI stuff, delegating any logic to the actual job object.

Comment: You may save the boilerplate code by using [ObservableProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty) with [ObservableObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject).

Answer (score 1):

> What is de convinient place to trigger the PropertyChanged?.Invoke(...)

My preference, is to have a OnPropertyChanged method, and a SetField method:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
    field = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    return true;
}

// Used like
public JobStatus Status
{
    get => status;
    set => SetField(ref status, value);
}
```

This tend to reduce code duplication when writing properties. And if you just set the property rather than the field you do not have to worry about calling PropertyChanged directly.

> Is it possible to trigger the PropertyChanged?.Invoke(...) on object level instead of on property level so it updates all binded properties without creating a PropertyChanged?.Invoke(...) for each individual property

You can invoke PropertyChanged with null or string.Empty to mark all properties as changed. See [PropertyChanged for all Properties in ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859946/c-wpf-propertychanged-for-all-properties-in-viewmodel). But it is not something I commonly use. I find that the pattern above is compact and easy enough that there is little benefit just to reduce code.

You can also do something like

```
public RJob MyJob
{
    get => myJob;
    set => SetField(ref myJob, value);
}
```

And setting that will update everything bound to a property of MyJob. But this does not seem relevant in your case, since you have a `ObservableCollection<RJob>`, and not a property.

Comment: Thanks for your usefull answer. I see that you also call the `OnPropertyChanged` in the class/object and not in the `ViewModel`. Seems to be common but it still feels like the wrong place to me as its view related and i prefer to split view and logic pretty hard. I will also check/test the suggestion in question you linked to. I do like the `SetField` suggestion (when the event is fired in the object/class). Unfortunately i cannot use it in this situation as most of the `Job` properties are not public setable.

Comment: @CodeNinja then make the property setters private? You may need to configure the binding to work with read-only properties, but it should work.  And I *do* usually put OnPropertyChanged on the viewModel. But I'm more pragmatic than dogmatic, so exceptions certainly do occur.